# Looping a Delete SP

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, while-loop, sql-server-2012

I need to some help trying to create some handling for this SP I'm creating which currently looks like this...

```
 alter PROCEDURE ArchiveCampaignData 

    @CampaignId INT,
    @DeleteBatchOf INT

     AS


BEGIN

BEGIN   

    DECLARE @Rowcount INT = 1

    WHILE @Rowcount > 0

    DELETE TOP (@DeleteBatchOf)FROM dbo.u_activity
    OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO u_activity_archive
    WHERE campaignId = @CampaignId

    SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
END


BEGIN   

    DECLARE @Rowcount2 INT = 1
    WHILE @Rowcount2 > 0

        DELETE TOP (@DeleteBatchOf) C
        OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO dbo.u_contact_archive
        FROM dbo.U_contact AS C
             INNER JOIN dbo.U_Campaigncontact AS CON WITH(NOLOCK)ON C.id = CON.contactId
        WHERE CON.campaignId = @CampaignId

        SET @Rowcount2 = @@ROWCOUNT

END

BEGIN   

    DECLARE @Rowcount3 INT = 1
    WHILE @Rowcount3 > 0

    DELETE TOP (@DeleteBatchOf) FROM u_campaignContact
    OUTPUT Deleted.* INTO u_campaignContact_archive
    WHERE campaignId = @CampaignId

    SET @Rowcount3 = @@ROWCOUNT

END


BEGIN   

    DECLARE @Rowcount4 INT = 1
    WHILE @Rowcount4 > 0

        DELETE TOP (@DeleteBatchOf) L
        OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO dbo.dxi_CDRLog_Archive
        FROM dbo.dxi_CDRLog AS L
             INNER JOIN dbo.u_campaignHdr AS H WITH(NOLOCK)ON L.qid = H.diallerCampaignId
        WHERE H.parentId = @CampaignId

        SET @Rowcount4 = @@ROWCOUNT

END


BEGIN   


        DECLARE @Rowcount5 INT = 1
        WHILE @Rowcount5 > 0

        DELETE TOP(@DeleteBatchOf) T
        OUTPUT Deleted.* INTO dxi_diallerStatsSmall_archive
        FROM dbo.dxi_diallerStatsSmall AS T
        INNER JOIN dbo.u_campaignHdr AS G WITH (NOLOCK) ON G.diallerCampaignId = T.campaign   
        WHERE G.id = @CampaignId

        SET @Rowcount5 = @@ROWCOUNT

 END

BEGIN

        DECLARE @Rowcount6 INT = 1
        WHILE @Rowcount6 > 0

        DELETE TOP(@DeleteBatchOf) FROM dbo.u_campaignHdr
        OUTPUT Deleted.* INTO u_campaignHdr_archive
        WHERE Id = @CampaignId OR parentId = @CampaignId

        SET @Rowcount6 = @@ROWCOUNT

END
END
```

the goal is for each block to loop in the SP to run at a time and once each block is completed that block will stop its transaction and it will move on to the next block as well as printing 'Completed' after each successful delete.

Any recommendations/Enhancements will be appreciated .

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Best idea - *don't*. You can always write a single `DELETE` query that performs what you want without a loop. What *do* you want? It looks like you *already* have that single DELETE but break it apart for no obvious reason

Comment: Are you having performance problems? Why are you using all those `NOLOCK` hints? These *won't* improve performance. NOLOCK means `Don't respect other transactions, I want to read dirty data` and probably end up deleting the wrong rows. How many rows are there? Are the ID, diallerCampaignId  covered by indexes? What does the execution plan look like?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos After each delete is done I need it to stop trying to look for those rows and move on. As this will currently just keep looking for data and not end.  There are 25000 rows to delete , and yes the ID columns are indexed

Comment: @virkboy what do you mean "stop trying to look for those rows"? A DELETE doesn't look for anything, it deletes a set of rows that match specific critera. 25K by the way is no data. *Why* are you using loops at all? Why are you trying to batch the deletions of only 25K rows?

Comment: @virkboy batched deletes are used to reduce the size of the transaction log when performing a really big delete. In your case though, you are moving data to an archive table. You could do so in less than a second if you partitioned your table by CampaignID and simply [switched the partition](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/9658.switching-partitions-example) you want from the active to the archive table. That's a metadata operation, not a deletion, which is why it takes less than a second and *doesn't* bloat the transaction log